# Bundler command bundle install --deployment not bundle all gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I am deploying a rails application, this is what I did currently:

Build application step:

1. git sync by a git hash tag
2. bundle gems into application self directory(vender/bundle).
3. precompile assets.
4. Build the application into a debian package(.deb).
5. At target machine, I just dpkg -i myapplication.deb to install it. That's.

Now the problem is step 2.

After I execute **bundle package --all** and **bundle install --deployment**, not all gems bundled into vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/, which are gems from a git path, not from default rubygems.org.

```
➜  luna-server git:(v0.1.0) ✗ bundle show rails
/Users/qichunren/code/work/luna-server/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails-3.2.11
➜  luna-server git:(v0.1.0) ✗ bundle show luna-channel
/Users/qichunren/code/work/luna-server/vendor/cache/luna-channel-31bb309440e5
```

So when I run my builded rails application on target machine, it show some gems not installed(eg:luna-channel), please bundle install, because it not at /vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/

Is there a way to make all gems from bundle cache into target bundle directory?

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: did you ever figure out a solution to this problem? Running into the same problem when trying to vendorize my ruby app. I'm considering to just manually copy my gems over since obviously bundler is the worst dependency manager ever. Never seen a tool this broken in so many exotic ways.

Comment: I have quick hack fix the problem, this is my git commit: https://github.com/qichunren/bundler/commit/192c822724f356f2573cabd4fd4ddc1a217b7d8b

But author don't think it is a bug: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/pull/2423 and
https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2422

Answer (score 0):

There is a `--path` option on `bundle install` [link to docs](http://gembundler.com/v1.2/bundle_install.html)

This tells bundler the exact path to install all of the gems.

Your style of development is atypical though so I highly recommend thoroughly reading the bundler docs and being very sure of what `bundle package` and `bundle install --deployment` do.

http://gembundler.com/v1.3/deploying.html
http://gembundler.com/v1.3/bundle_package.html

It is sometimes difficult to see when they are talking about the dev machine or the production machine.

Comment: No, --path option is not useful for me, I just want to bundle into default directory: ./vendor/bundle.

The problem is: Not all types gems bundled into ./vendor/bundle, gems from a git repository or a path is still left at ./vendor/cache. And I don't want ./vendor/cache directory left at my build package. This is problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem, code here: https://github.com/qichunren/bundler/commit/192c822724f356f2573cabd4fd4ddc1a217b7d8b

I don't if this change is suitable for total project, but this change fixed my problem.